# Access Value in Dictionary using Random Number

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access the value from a dictionary using a random number, but I am lost, can someone please guide?

Here is what I have:

```
var themes = ["Halloween": "", "Sports": "⛳️⚽️" , "Faces": "", "Animal": ""]

// This Does not work for some reason?
lazy var themeRandomNumber = themes.count.arc4random
lazy var currentTheme = themes[themeRandomNumber]

//Cannot subscript a value of type[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'
```

This makes sense since, I am trying to access the key using an `Int` when it is obviously a `String`, but not sure how to proceed?

```
lazy var currentEmoji = themes[currentTheme]

extension Int{
    var arc4random: Int{
        if self > 0 {
            return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(abs(self))))
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `Swift` are you using? `Swift 4.2` has [special methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995361-randomelement) to get random elements of collections, so may just use them.

Comment: Swift 4.2 and thanks for the heads up but I am wanting to proceed using this approach if that is okay? :)

Comment: Do you want a random emoji? Right now you only choose a random theme.

Comment: @PulkitAgrawal, they you should turn dictionary into array before trying to access it via integer index.

Comment: Use the simplest option: `themes.randomElement()?.value.randomElement()`.

Comment: Like a set, a dictionary is not an ordered collection, so it doesn't make any sense to ask for the first, second, or *n*th element of the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace

```
lazy var currentEmoji = themes[currentTheme]
```

with

```
var currentTheme = themes.randomElement()
print(currentTheme?.value) //Optional("⛳️⚽️")
print(currentTheme?.key)  //Optional("Sports")
```

Here [`randomElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995361-randomelement) is new property which you can use to get random element.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not accessing the key of your dictionary, you need to select `"Halloween"`, `"Sports"`, `"Faces"` or `"Animal"` - your `themes` dict's keys.

You can use some custom mapping method with Int.random(in: 0...3) or a `Keys` enum conforming to `CaseIterable`, and then you need to select a random character (emoji) in the `String` for your given Key (via a random number in the range `0..<string.length`).

**EDIT**

With Swift 4.2+ (Xcode 10) you can use [randomElement()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995361-randomelement):

```
var themes = ["Halloween": "", "Sports": "⛳️⚽️" , "Faces": "", "Animal": ""]
var randomEmoji = themes.randomElement()?.value.randomElement()
```